# Solving a distributional equation

Tags: analysis

I'm a bit new to the theory of distributions, and I'm not too sure how I should proceed with these sorts of problems. Example:

Let g(x) be a distribution and solve the following equation for even and odd g(x):

$(x^2-25)g(x) = 0$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** : $x^2-25=0$ only at $x=-5$ and $x=5$. Hence $g$ must be $0$ on $\mathbb{R} \backslash \{-5,5\}$. You can deduce that $$supp(g) \subset \{-5,5\}.$$ Can you procede further ?

Comment: Not quite. I know that g(x) should be some sort of linear combination of the Dirac delta function and, I think, a constant function. But I'm not really sure where to go from here.